# Complex queries with JPA Criteria builder

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, builder

Can someone suggest me how to build up the following query using JPA Criteria builder API?

```
SELECT id,status,created_at from transactions where status='1' 
   and currency='USD' and appId='123' order by id
```

It's better if I can find a solution which creates dynamically based on the parameters given as a `Map<String,String>` using metamodel classes or any other way.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's like this (without metamodel):

```
Map<String, Object> params = ...;
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();           
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();     
Root<Transaction> r = cq.from(Transaction.class);

Predicate p= cb.conjunction();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param: params.entrySet())
    p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(r.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue()));

cq.multiselect(r.get("id"), r.get("status"), r.get("created_at"))
    .where(p)
    .orderBy(cb.asc(r.get("id")));

List<Tuple> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Or with metamodel (typesafe, but a bit wordy):

```
Map<SingularAttribute<Transaction, ?>, Object> params = ...;
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();           
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();     
Root<Transaction> r = cq.from(Transaction.class);

Predicate p= cb.conjunction();
for (Map.Entry<SingularAttribute<Transaction, ?>, Object> param: params.entrySet())
    p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(r.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue()));

cq.multiselect(r.get(Transaction_.id), r.get(Transaction_.status), 
          r.get(Transaction_.created_at))
    .where(p)
    .orderBy(cb.asc(r.get(Transaction_.id)));

List<Tuple> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```