# JPQL aggregate functions with Specifications

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, specification-pattern

I need to make a JPQL query with aggregate functions, using Specifications. I would like something like

```
myQuery="select sum(et.durationMinutes/et.percent) from EmployeeTimekeeping et"
myQuery.where(specifications)
myQuery.getResultList();
```

I'm trying to use a Specifications object instead of my where clause.
Is there any way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Expression in CriteriaBuilder

To write query like that you could use [Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html) class.
For example to do sum like that you could write :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Number> q = cb.createQuery(Number.class);
Root<EmployeeTimekeeping > t = q.from(EmployeeTimekeeping .class);

Expression<Double> sum = cb.sum(t.<Double>get("durationMinutes"), t.<Double>get("percent"));
q.select(sum.alias("sum"));
```

to query built like that you could add your specification however you want to.

Question like yours was [asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345571/how-to-build-jpql-queries-when-parameters-are-dynamic?rq=1), from what I've read, easiest solution to build dynamic where clause is to use CriteriaAPI.