# Java Criteria API: Select single column from one-to-many relationship table

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpql, criteria-api

I am trying to select a single column from a related table.  I have a table (Item) with many Values.  I would like to select Value.valueString.

Basically, the query is supposed to pass in a bunch of values and pull any ValueFields that contain those values.  The SQL might look something like this:

```
select ItemValues.valueString from ItemEntity
    join StockItem on ItemEntity.stockItemId = StockItem.id
    join ItemValues on ItemEntity.id = ItemValues.itemId
where StockItem.vendor = vendorId 
AND (ItemValues.valueString like '%test%' OR ItemValues.valueString like '%test2%'...);
```

Here is my code:

```
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<String> query = builder.createQuery(String.class);

        final Root<ItemEntity> root = query.from(ItemEntity.class);

        query.select(root.join("ItemValues").<String>get("ValueString"));

        final List<Predicate> filters = new LinkedList<Predicate>();

        filters.add(builder.equal(root.join("StockItem").get("id"), vendorNumber));
        final List<Predicate> filterNamesCriteria = new LinkedList<Predicate>();

        if (filenames.length > 0) {

            for (String fileName : filenames) {
                filterNamesCriteria.add(builder.like(root.join("ItemValues").<String>get("ValueString"), fileName));
            }
            filters.add(builder.or(filterNamesCriteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        }

        query.where(filters.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

        final TypedQuery<String> resolvedQuery = this.entityManager.createQuery(query);

        return resolvedQuery.getResultList();
```

I want the result to return a List of Strings (valueString column), but it's not returning anything.

Am I doing something wrong?  When I say "builder.createQuery(String.class)", is that correct?

Comment: You need a Tuple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842122/complex-queries-with-jpa-criteria-builder

Comment: But I'm only selecting one value.  Isn't a tuple for multiselects?

Comment: @a.drew.b The OP doesn't need a tuple, the OP can achieve this using an IN operation. `select .. from ... where value IN :collection`. I could make an example but I don't feel like figuring out how the entities are mapped. OP please show how the entities are related (classes).

Comment: Item has many ItemValues
Item has one StockItem

I can't do an "IN" operation because ItemValues.valueString could contain multiple concatenated values (ex: value1;value2;value3 stored as a semi-colon-delimited string).  So I must do a (LIKE 'foo' OR LIKE 'bar' OR LIKE 'fubar')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

```
filters.add(builder.equal(root.join("StockItem").get("id"), vendorNumber));
```

I was joining based on the StockItem id and not the StockItem.itemNumber

I used two queries to solve the issue of joining the Itemvalues map (it was returning 32,000+ results)